Interpreting Negative Binomial residual plot
I ran a negative binomial regression for bike crashes data in 125 block groups in Santa Barbara. The equation looks like:
MASS::glm.nb(Crashes ~ network coverage + network density + 
    intersection density + complexity + offset(log(number of bike trips))

I got a residual plot with curves as shown in the plot below. Does it mean that the relationship is non-linear? And I don't know what to proceed with this: should I add in non-linear terms or I should try another model, or else? It will be great if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

I tried the residual plot from DHARMa and this is the plot I got:


Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please edit the question to say what package(s) and functions you used to fit the model and to generate the plot. There are several possibilities even just in R, so it helps to be specific. Also, say how many different values of bike network connectivity there are. What looks like multiple nonlinear "curves" in the residuals might just represent variation between different values of bike network connectivity. Also, see this answer and its links for what might be a better way to evaluate your model.

Thanks for your reply! I edited the question to include what you suggested!

The obvious pattern of curves in your first chart is presumably a consequence of the number of crashes taking integer values while your predictions can take real values (though I would have expected straight lines with slope $-1$ since the predicted value plus the residual should add up to an integer number of crashes).  Such patterns do not tell you whether your model is good or bad.

Could it be that I included offset term? And according to the simulated residual plot from DHARMa, there's a quantile deviation. Do you any thoughts on that?

tl;dr As @Henry says, the patterns seen in your first plot are an expected consequence of the discreteness of your response variable: if you plot a smoothed line through the points you'll see the result is pretty flat. Using one of the models developed below:

It looks like the DHARMa patterns may indeed be offset-induced. Read on ...
simulate data
library(glmmTMB) ## for sim
library(DHARMa)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)


simfun <- function(nn = 100, seed = NULL, family = nbinom2,
                   off = TRUE) {
   if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
   params <- list(beta = rnorm(5), betadisp = 1)
   dd <- replicate(4, rnorm(nn), 4) |> 
      as.data.frame() |>
      setNames(c("net_cover", "net_dens", "int_dens", "complex")) |>
      transform(n_trips = rlnorm(nn, meanlog = 4, sdlog = 1))
    form <- Crashes1 ~ net_cover + net_dens + int_dens + complex
    if (off) form <- update(form, . ~ . + offset(log(n_trips)))
    dd$Crashes1 <- simulate_new(form[-2], family = family,
             newparams = params,
             newdata = dd)[[1]]
    return(list(data = dd, form = form))
}

It does look like there might be an issue with offsets: here are the simulated-residual tests in a model with offsets:
dd1 <- simfun(seed = 101)
m1 <- with(dd1, MASS::glm.nb(form, data = data))
plot(simulateResiduals(m1))


And here it is with the offset omitted:
dd2 <- simfun(seed = 101, off = FALSE)
m2 <- with(dd2, MASS::glm.nb(form, data = data))
plot(simulateResiduals(m2))


Code for fitted vs residual above:
ggplot(augment(m2), aes(.fitted, .resid)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()


I looked for offset-related issues on the DHARMa issues page, but none of the hits here jumped out at me as being relevant (I might have missed something)
You shouldn't take a conclusion based on only two simulations too seriously.  You might want to try this with a few different random-number seeds and see if the pattern is consistent.
My quantile pattern is quadratic, unlike yours (which is linear). That may just have to do with the detailed structure of the data (e.g., the magnitude of the offsets). Try simulating data that looks more like what you actually have and see if/how the patterns change.
glmmTMB knows about some different versions of the negative binomial (nbinom1, nbinom12); it occurred to me to experiment with these to see what kind of residual plots they gave, but I didn't get around to it (you can do this by setting a different value of family in the simfun() call, although nbinom12 has an additional parameter that might require adjusting things a bit more ...)
performance::check_model() gives reasonably good results for both of these examples. It seems to think that the variance-mean relationship is misspecified for example 2, not sure why ...

